# Is there any multiple file uploader control in asp.net (just the same as pre-image)?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, multifile-uploader

[image: this is the sample for our project]

this is what my project need for multiple file uploader control, is there any control can do the same thing as it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the [Flajaxian File Uploader](http://flajaxianfileupload.codeplex.com/).  It's a free open source ASP.Net control for doing multiple uploads.  It does require the use of Flash in the browser, which is a dependency you will need to consider.

It describes itself as:

> a .NET web control designed for
>   asynchronous file upload of multiple
>   files at the same time, without a page
>   post back and with a progress bar
>   indicating the current upload
>   progress. This control does not
>   require full trust environment. The
>   control can be extended with the
>   addition of server side and client
>   side functions. Flajaxian FileUploader
>   uses Adobe Flash Player 9 or higher
>   Flash Player for the file upload
>   request.

Comment: Hi Pervez, Would you please tell me how to code this in server side?